# “Where all are you going?” Grammar and alternatives

Tags: grammar, expressions

How do you ask someone which places (multiple) they’re going to: is “where all are you going to?” correct grammar? What’s a correct, better and concise way to ask this? The intent is to ask about the multiple places or hint that they should be going to multiple places. The phrase mentioned above doesn’t sound like native English.

Edit: It could be places or events in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, "*where all are you going to?*" is not correct English.

You could ask "*What are all the places to which you are going?*".

or simpler "*what places are you going to?*". The plural "places" lets the other person know that you want to know about more than one.

Comment: Correct or not, you're more likely to get a funny look by saying "What are all the places to which you are going?" than "Where all are you going?" The latter is perfectly acceptable in casual, conversational English. If it's ok to be more specific, the OP can simply say "What cities are you visiting?" This is IMO much more natural than your examples.

Comment: @TypeIA Agreed, but my first option was to try and correct the grammar of the OP **as posted**, then provide a better alternative. As a native BrE speaker I've never heard  "Where all are you going?" , to me it is very strange. Your other "cities" option is fine as well.